# SublimeREPL - How to run current file in other languages?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimerepl

SublimeREPL gives the option of running the current file in python but it doesn't give this option for other languages. Is there a way to configure it to run the current file in say PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run any file for which a REPL is running. So, simply start a PHP REPL in Sublime, then select **`Tools → SublimeREPL → Eval in REPL → File`** and you're all set.